# WF4 workflow versions where service contract changes

Tags: version-control, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I just successfully implemented a WF4 "versioning" system using WCF's Routing Service.  I had a version1 workflow service to which I added a new Decision activity and saved it as a version2 service.  So now I have 2 endpoints (with identical service contracts, i.e. all Receive activities are the same for both service) and a router that checks the content of a message (a "versionId" string on the object that all of my Receive's accept as an argument) to decide which endpoint to hit.

My question is, while this works fine when no changes are made to the service contract, how to I handle the need to add or remove methods from my service contract and create a version3 service?  My original thought was, when I add the service reference to my client, I use the latest workflow service's endpoint to get the latest service contract.  Then, in the config file, I change the endpoint I connect to to the router's endpoint.  But this won't work if v1 and v2 have a different contract than v3.  My proxy will have v3's methods and forget all about v1 and v2.

Any ideas of how to handle this?  Should I create an actual service contract interface in my workflow solution (instead of just supplying a ServiceContractName in my Receive activities)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the WCF contract changes your client will need to be aware of the additional operations and when to call them. I have used the active bookmarks, it contains the WCF operation, from the persistence store in some applications to have the client app adapt to the workflow dynamically by checking the enabled bookmarks and enabling/disabling UI controls based on that. The client will still have to be updated when new operations are added to a new version of the workflow.

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand from your answer how my client would become aware of the service contract changes. I imagine the following situation.  V1 has, say, 3 receive calls.  The service contract is "implied" (i.e. I didn't specifically create one, but put a name in the "Service Contract Name" in the WF designer).  If V2 removes one of those receives and adds a new one, how do I make my client understand that the service contract should be the union of the 2?  Should I version my service contract names in the workflow so the client ends up with multiple service contracts?

Comment: How did the client become aware of what the original service contract was and in what order to call operations? I am guessing because of Add Service Reference and documentation. A change is the same thing. Do an Update Service Reference and tell them what to call. There really is no difference from the first contract.

Comment: Yes, because of an Add Service Reference.  My point was, though, my client still needs to know what the V1 service contract was so that it can V1 workflows that are in the persistence store.  If I do what you say, just update my service reference, it will only get V2's service contract.  I need the combination of the 2 I would think.

Comment: Since WF4 doesn't support a "contract-first" workflow design, and all service contracts are inferred by the client consuming the service, there is no way (that I'm aware of) to define an all-inclusive service contract (one that defines operations for version 1 and version 2) and have my client implement all of these operations.  That way, regardless of what version the persisted workflow is from, it can resume.

Comment: As WF4 doesn't support versioning workflows a second version of a workflow is technically a complete new workflow and nothing to V1. So as a result there is a second WorkflowServiceHost and a second endpoint so an all-inclusive service contract doesn't work anyway.

Comment: So, basically, I need to ditch the routing service and just add a service reference to my client for each of my workflow services?

Comment: The routing service works well in the scenario when the public contract stays the same but the workflow implementation changes. In that case the client need not know anything changed. Keep in in place for those cases. If the public contract changes the client app needs to know what the valid contract is for each workflow instance and the routing service isn't going to help there.

Answer (score 1):

While WCF was young I heard a few voices arguing that endpoint versioning (for web services that is) should be accomplished by using a folder structure. I never got to the point of trying  it out myself, but just analyzing the consequences of such a strategy seems to me as a splendid solution. I have no production experience of WCF, but am about to launch a rather comprehensive solution using version 4.0 of .NET (ASP.NET, WCF, WF...) and at this stage I would argue that using a folder structure to separate versions of endpoints would be a good solution.

The essence of such a strategy would be to never change or remove the contract of an endpoint (a specific version) until you are 100% sure that it is not used any more. While your services evolves you would just add new contracts and endpoints. This could lead to code duplication if one is not such a structured developer as one should be. But by introducing a service facade the duplication would be insignificant

Answer (score 0):

I have been through the same situation. You can maintain the version by the help of custom implementation. save the Workflow Service URL in Database. And invoke them as per desire.

You can get the information about calling the WF Service with the URL by the client.

http://rajeevkumarsrivastava.blogspot.in/2014/08/consume-workflow-service-45-from-client.html

Hope this helps